# Automate query joining SQL to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a dataset in SQL Server that I need to join with data in Excel, and I need this to be refreshed every hour.  Due to permissions limitations at work I'm not allowed to do this via ODBC or any type of link.  In the past I've done some automation using batch files, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this in this situation.

My idea is to have an automated script in Task Manager run the SQL Server query to get the SQL dataset, then join that dataset to the Excel data via a common key, and then output the final result to Excel.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you use Power Query? That is built for that kind of stuff.